# Distribution of a vector function of a scalar random variable

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ is a real random variable with some density function $f_X(x)$. Let $\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{g}(X)$, where $\mathbf{g}(.): \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$.

Is there a general way to represent the density $f_{\mathbf{Y}}(\mathbf{y})$?

For example, consider a simple case, $X \sim Uniform(0,1)$. $(Y_1, Y_2) = (X+1, X+2)$. Is there a closed form expression for the density of $(Y_1, Y_2)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

**Edit:**
Dirac measures are permitted. In the above simple case, I presume the density could be $$f_{(Y_1, Y_2)}(y_1, y_2) = \begin{cases}
\delta(y_1-y_2+1) && 1 \leq y_1 \leq 2 \text{ and } 2 \leq y_2 \leq 3\\
0 && \text{else}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: I'm not sure your Dirac measure works the way you want; it would still seem to assign positive measure to individual *points*, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example was good, because it illustrates exactly why this *can't* be done in general. You cannot find a density function for that example, because the support of $(Y_1, Y_2)$, and hence the support of its density function $f$ (should it exist), would be the line segment $\{x + 1, x + 2: x \in [0, 1]\}$. Because that set has measure $0$ in $\mathbb R^2$, we would necessarily obtain $\iint_R f \, \textrm d A = 0$ for any region $R$.

The issue is dimensionality; presuming $g$ is well-behaved at all (e.g. continuous is enough to cause the problem), the support of $Y$ will necessarily be one-dimensional, and it will not be possible to furnish a density function in the higher-dimensional space.

Comment: What if Dirac measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are permitted?

Comment: I think my answer is: while you can probably play around with the measure on $\mathbb R^2$ to get something interesting, it won't have an associated *density* function in any traditional sense -- and I think it has to be more complicated than a Dirac measure, more like a pullback to $\mathbb R$. (Even the Dirac delta function isn't actually a *function* in any reasonable sense; it's just a notational cheat to indicate an interesting measure, and I don't think it's sensible to use the word "density" to describe it.)